# Blank PDF being generated from ActiveReports/WebAPI

Tags: c#, angularjs, pdf, asp.net-web-api, activereports

On a project I am working on, I'm building a feature that lets users generate a report - in my case, it will go on an envelope - on-demand from information stored in our database.  The problem I'm trying to solve, is that a blank PDF is being generated.

I've tried some sanity checks.  First I set a breakpoint in Visual Studio and ensured that the models being passed to the report had fixed data; the reports were blank.  Next, I tried including a static label that's not tied to any data, to determine if it's a report data-binding issue - the static label is not appearing in the generated report either.

More stymying, is that I've used similar code in the past without issue.  I have no idea why a blank PDF file would be generated in this case.

I've read the 'Similar Questions' provided by StackOverflow, specifically [this question from one year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581784/how-to-a-pdf-stream-in-web-api-from-exporttostream-of-crystal-report), but it had no answers, and thus nothing to learn from it.  I've also tried the requisite Google searches, but found nothing relevant.

The only thing I cannot provide is the actual ActiveReport itself.  I've checked this for Silly Programmer Errors™ like having everything hidden, or transparent labels, or similar silly things.  *Unfortunately*, I've made no such errors.

**Report Code:**

```
public partial class EnvelopeReport : SectionReport
{
    public EnvelopeReport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal void RunReport(IEnumerable<PrintedAddress> model)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            DataSource = model;
        }

        Run();
    }

    private void OnReportStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Document.Printer.PrinterName = string.Empty;
        PageSettings.PaperKind = PaperKind.Number10Envelope;

        PageSettings.Margins.Top = 0.25f;
        PageSettings.Margins.Left = 0.5f;
        PageSettings.Margins.Right = 0.5f;
        PageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0.25f;
    }
}
```

**Web API Controller Code:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage EnvelopeReport(int addressId, string attentionTo, bool isConfidential)
    {
        Address address = AddressRepository.GetAddress(addressId, true);
        List<PrintedAddress> models = new List<PrintedAddress>
        {
            new PrintedAddress(address, attentionTo, isConfidential)
        };

        var report = new EnvelopeReport();
        report.RunReport(models);

        var pdfExporter = new ActiveReportsPdfExporter();
        var reportBytes = pdfExporter.ExportPdf(report);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(reportBytes, 0, reportBytes.Length);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "Envelope Report.pdf"
        };

        return response;
    }
```

**PDF Exporter:**

```
public class ActiveReportsPdfExporter
{
    private readonly PdfExport _pdfExport;

    public ActiveReportsPdfExporter()
    {
        _pdfExport = new PdfExport();
    }

    public byte[] ExportPdf(SectionReport report)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            _pdfExport.Export(report.Document, stream);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public Stream ExportPdfToStream(SectionReport report)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        _pdfExport.Export(report.Document, stream);
        return stream;
    }
}
```

**Client Service (Angular):**

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app').factory('addressSvc', [
        '$http', addressSvc
    ]);

    function addressSvc($http) {
        var service = {
            printAddress: function(addressId, attentionTo, someFlag) {
                var args = {
                    'addressId': thingId,
                    'attentionTo': attentionTo,
                    'isConfidential': isConfidential
                };

                return $http.get('/api/common/EnvelopeReport', { 'params': args });
            }
        };

        return service;
    }
})();
```

**Client Controller (Angular):**

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app').controller('someCtrl', [
        '$window', 'addressSvc', controller
    ]);

    function controller($window, addressSvc) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.attentionTo = '';    // Bound to UI.
        vm.isConfidential = ''; // Also bound to UI.
        vm.address = {};        // Unimportant how we get this.
        vm.printAddress = printAddress;

        function printAddress() {
            addressSvc.printAddress(vm.address.id, vm.attentionTo, vm.isConfidential)
                .then(function(result) {
                    var file = new Blob([result], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                    if(window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, 'Envelope.pdf');
                    } else {
                        $window.open(fileURL);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
)();
```

**Question:** Why is this code generating an empty PDF?  I've used the Report/API Controller structure successfully in the past to generate PDFs, but usually in the context of MVC, not Web API.  Another potential point of failure is the client code - I've not previously passed reports between server and client this way.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out my server-side code was *completely sane.*  The Client code was off.

Instead of Blobbing the data returned from the server and all of that work, what I instead needed to do was build a URL...and call `$window.open(url);`  This is because my server code as it stands will return the PDF file as-is.